# how can I define a function of a derived template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to define the function find from `class FHhashQPwFind`. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

I put the coment "HERE IS THE ERROR" where the compiler says:

> error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

```
template <class Object, typename KeyType>
class FHhashQPwFind: public FHhashQP<Object>
{
public:
    const Object find(const KeyType & key);
protected:
        int myHashKey(const KeyType & key) const;
    int findPosKey( const KeyType & key ) const;
};
template <class Object, typename KeyType>
const Object FHhashQPwFind<Object>::find(const JeyType & key)//HERE IS THE ERROR
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd certainly try

```
const Object FHhashQPwFind<Object, KeyType>::find(const KeyType & key)
```

Also care you named it `JeyType` in your template parameters.

The error is because your method is declared as

```
 FHhashQPwFind<Object>
```

When it needs its second parameter KeyType:

```
 FHhashQPwFind<Object, KeyType>
```

When writing the method.

Comment: Dont forget to flag answered! And no problem!